# Make a CPT posts and pages loop (with Elementor)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode, elementor

I have a Wordpress website made with CPT (Custom post types) and Elementor builder. I added this code to functions.php:

```
add_shortcode( 'nextpg', 'next_shortcode' );

function next_shortcode($atts) {
$next= get_next_post(true);
return get_post_permalink($next);
}

add_shortcode( 'prevpg', 'prev_shortcode' );

function prev_shortcode($atts) {
$prev= get_previous_post(true);
return get_post_permalink($prev);
}
```

I'm using this shortcodes [nextpg] & [prevpg] that I inserted into my website builder's button (Elementor). It allows to navigate through posts / pages (also  CPT).

Help me to make code to loop the navigation (go from the last to first and vice versa)? The code needs to work for all types of posts / pages (and for CPT).

Thanks

Comment: Well if you get no _next_ post, you would have to get the _first_ post instead; and if you do not get a _previous_ one, then the _last_ one instead.

Comment: @CBroe Could you write code?

Comment: No. This site is not a code-writing service, it is always expected that _you_ make an actual attempt first. We can discuss any problems you might run into while doing so, once you show us what you tried.

Comment: @CBroe yes, I get it. I have extended code with loop, but it is not working:

Comment: _“I have extended code with loop”_ - meaning what? _Show us_ what you tried, and give us a _proper_ problem description along with it. (“Not working” is not one, [ask].)